# When to use "al estilo (de)"?

Tags: gramática

I'm writing an article about a style of play (soccer). I want to use "*al estilo Messi*" as the title/header.

Would this be a correct use? I know I can say "*al estilo DE Messi*" or "*El estilo (de) Messi*" but that is less of an eye catcher it seems. Can I simply use "*Al estilo Messi*" without putting any subject in front of that?

Comment: Short answer: yes, you can use the title you suggest. In fact, it sounds me quite better without the "de". I'm sorry I don't have the time right now for a better explanation.

Comment: I asked https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/two-nouns-in-a-row-or-is-it-ok-to-omit-de some time ago. It's relevant here, I think. Your question is a very good one, a complement and by no means a duplicate of mine. Both touch on Spanish as it is used in the real world, using constructions you often won't learn in a grammar book.

Answer (score 1):

Using "El estilo de Messi" is talking about how Messi plays. On the other hand, "El estilo Messi" is talking about a way of play, that is played by Messi.

Is like "Messi's style" or "Messi style", talking about the style of Messi or taliking about the style "called" Messi.

For an article I think "El estilo Messi" is way more powerfull.

Comment: Note it's **Al** estilo Messi, not **El** estilo Messi. That preposition changes the meaning of the sentence.